# Homotopic curves

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, homotopy-theory

I have a problem with understanding homotopy in loop curves. So I have these two curves σ and υ. It is defined an operation * such that we add the second curve at the first one creating another curve. I need to know if this new curve is homotopic to the original curves (or other curves from a given set). I know that a curve is homotopic with another curve if I can "bend" them to obtain the same line. But what  happens when curves are loop?[image: the operation made on the generators curve]

[image]
is the curve generated from σ and υ homotopic to this one? and why?

Comment: Let me see if I've got this correct.  Is the space in question essentially a Euclidean plane with three points (the red dots) removed?

Comment: no, red point are constant. you cannot remove them "think about them as obstacles to the curve. What i cannot understand is which are the requisites for a loop curve to be homotopic to another loop curve

Comment: there is indeed what is seems to be a 4th point of the first pic top left. But it was not intended to be drowned, just consider the 3 constants points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first state a theorem, whenever $\alpha_1\in L(X,x_0)$ homotopic to $\alpha_2\in L(X,x_0)$ and $\beta_1\in L(X,x_0)$ homotopic to $\beta_2\in L(X,x_0)$ we have $\alpha_1*\beta_1\in L(X,x_0)$ homotopic to $\alpha_2*\beta_2\in L(X,x_0)$ where $L(X,x_0)$ denote set of all loops in $X$ based at $x_0\in X$.

Now if possible let $\gamma_1*\delta_1$ is homotopic to $\gamma_2*\delta_2$ then we have $[\gamma_1*\delta_1]=[\gamma_2*\delta_2]$ also $[\gamma_1]=[\gamma_2]$ therefore we have $[\gamma_1]^{-1}[\gamma_1*\delta_1]=[\gamma_2]^{-1}[\gamma_1*\delta_1]$ i.e. $[\delta_1]=[\delta_2]$.But according to the second picture we have $[\delta_1]=[\delta_2]^2$ that gives $ \delta_2$ is homotopic to constant loop based at $x_0$ , which is impossible as inside of $\delta_2$ contains a hole.

So the conclusion is $\gamma_1*\delta_1$ is not homotopic to $\gamma_2*\delta_2$ .

[image]

[image]

Comment: Elements of $\pi(X,x_0)$ aren't curves, but equivalence classes of curves.  So it should be something like "whenever $[\gamma_1]=[\gamma_2]\in\pi_1(X,x_0)$ and $[\delta_1]=[\delta_2]\in\pi_1(X,x_0)$, then $[\gamma_1*\delta_1]=[\gamma_2*\delta_2]\in\pi_1(X,x_0)$".

Comment: @Aweygan , I have corrected my answer , I think it now gives the answer of the question. Thank you for pointed out my mistake.

Comment: So if I get it right in my example the generate curve  σ *υ is not homotopic to the curve π? Or if I'm wrong can you explain a little bit more intuitively why I am wrong?

Comment: I think I am understanding, but why in this case δ1∈L(X,x0) homotopic to δ2∈L(X,x0) ? According to the drawing they shouldn't since one "loops" 2 red dots and the other one "loops" only one or am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry for another fault in my argument, actually  I haven't observe holes given in  the picture carefully.Now I presented the correct argument. Hence you are correct i.e. $\sigma*\upsilon$ is not homotopic to $\pi$.